# Is there a way to read ABRecordID using iOS Contacts framework?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, contacts, addressbook

I'm upgrading an app that reads iOS contacts using the old, deprecated AddressBook framework. The upgrade uses the current Contacts framework instead.

The old AddressBook framework used a 32-bit integer [ABRecordID](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook/abrecordid) as a record unique identifier. I use these in my app database. The new framework appears to replace it with CNContact [identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact/1403103-identifier?changes=_2), which is a UUID string.

I need to be able to read ABRecordIDs in order to upgrade existing data to use the new framework. Is there any way to read ABRecordID using the new Contacts framework?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you ever find an answers? If so please post it.